# call servlet by jsp without form submit

Tags: jsp, servlets

In my application have menu-bar like this,

Sports

so when i click on sport button i want to call the "getlink" servlet and submit the value "sport". I tried several methods ,but non of them got it right.

this my servlet

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String vdo_type = request.getParameter("Science");

              int page = 1;
        int recordsPerPage = 10;
        if(request.getParameter("page") != null)
            page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
      //  EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();
        Getlink_Dao be=new Getlink_Dao();
        List<Utube_to> list = be.getRecentAdd((page-1)*recordsPerPage,
                                 recordsPerPage,vdo_type);
        int noOfRecords = be.getNoOfRecords();
        int noOfPages = (int) Math.ceil(noOfRecords * 1.0 / recordsPerPage);
        request.setAttribute("allvdos", list);
        request.setAttribute("noOfPages", noOfPages);
        request.setAttribute("currentPage", page);
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("Home.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response); 


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While building the menu itself append query string to that href link like this. Then it will send that value to your servlet

```
<li><a href="getlink?linkname=sport"></a></li>
```

then access that sport value/any other clicked link value in your servlet as follows

```
String vdo_type = request.getParameter("linkname");
```